# Syntax error on php5.3, works on php5.6

Tags: php, pdo

The following PDO function works on php 5.6 but gives error on php 5.3 which is the version of the cpanel im using. im unable to update the cpanel php version so i need to find a workaround..

```
$biq= $db ->prepare($biqQuery);

$biq->execute(['biqid' => $_GET['itemselector']]);
```

the error is:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in /home/mydomain/public_html/helpers/biq.php on line 38

I think it has something to do with array definitions in php5.3 which is supposed to be `array();` instead of `[];`

However, i have no idea how can i convert this into that format.

any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: `['foo','bar']` -> `array('foo', 'bar')`. it's not black magic or anything.

Comment: dunno why i was so scared to try the black magic. thanks :)